# I get an error message when trying to retrieve a Drive folder in my Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I get this error when trying to retrieve a folder:
Exception: Invalid argument: fields

This was working fine for a while and all the sudden it broke. Any advice?

The code is simply:

```
var folderID = "Abcdefgh";
var parent = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID); 
var files = parent.searchFiles("test");
```

Comment: Share your full code or at least the part that the error appears.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Isn't "folderId" the invalid argument?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this. The issue was in the next line. It should be

```
var files = parent.searchFiles("title contains 'test' ");
```

Now I am not sure why it was working before, but I guess it doesn't matter much. Thanks for responding.